# Saving the image as png rotate image to 90 degrees in MATLA

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I use the following code to save the image to file

```
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits','normalized');
set(gcf, 'PaperPosition', [0 0 1 1]);
set(gcf,'PaperOrientation','l');
print -dpng graphs/p1_effect_of_count_and_selB;
```

And the image is saved as
[image]

I tried using `set(fig,'PaperOrientation',portrait');` as suggested [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/338769-why-is-the-png-of-my-figure-rotated-90-degrees) but in this case no images is saved. Also, I am not using `print(fig,'-dpng',pngName);` to save file. Can someone suggest a solution for `print -dpng graphs/pngName;`

Comment: `set(gcf,'PaperOrientation','l');` this is making it go landscape. Just change that

Comment: When I remove that, the image is not saved as a square, instead, it becomes a rectangle with a width of 1 and height of 2.  Either removing that line or changing it to `set(gcf,'PaperOrientation','p');` gives the same effect.

Comment: Don't set the Paper... properties, set the Position property of the figure, and use `-r300` or whatever resolution you want in the `print` call. By default the paper aspect ratio will mimic the screen aspect ratio.

Comment: I would advise to use the [`export_fig` tool](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/) and not worry about things like that again.